# Excel VBA Vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Preciso que o VLOOKUP do código a seguir tenha como argumento de valor procurado a coluna A, ou seja, não pode ficar -16, pois pode ter colunas variáveis na planilha.

Estava assim:

```
    For i = 4 To ultimalinha_RESUMO             
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-16],PENDENTES!C2:C6,5,0),0)"               
   Next i
```

Eu fiz assim:

```
 For i = 4 To ultimalinha_RESUMO
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1).Value, PENDENTES.Range("B:F"), 9, 0)                   
 Next i
```

Mas não deu certo.

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Debugue. Você tem certeza de que o erro está nessa linha? Talvez sua ```ultimalinha_RESUMO``` esteja com valor menor do que 4 no começo, e ele nem entre no ```For```. Pode ser que outra planilha esteja ativa, e o ```Cells()``` esteja retornando valor do lugar errado. Eu recomendo colocar um ponto de parada na linha do ```VLookup``` e conferir os valores de cada argumento em tempo de execução. Se isso não der um insight sobre o problema, comente aqui e coloque os detalhe do erro.

Comment: Outra possibilidade pode ser a forma como o VBA está interpretando ```Cell(i, 1).Value```. você pode testar tirar o ".Value" e passar só a referência da célula, ou seja: ```Cell(i, 1)```, sem o ```.Value```. Às vezes o VBA calcula ou deixa de calcular o valor e isso afeta seu resultado.